# (local:page1) in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

thes code in uwp

```
<StackLayout >
                <local:page1 />
</StackLayout>
```

What is the equivalent code in xamarin.forms ?
error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="Haill_Xamarin.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <local:page1 /> // error this code in xamarin.forms
        </StackLayout>    
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Do you have the local namespace defined in the XAML?  If you are getting an error message, it is usually considered helpful to tell us WHAT THE ERROR is.

Comment: Error  'local' is an undeclared prefix. Line 20, position 18.

Answer (score 2):

You should be declaring local at the top of your XAML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Haill_Xamarin;assembly=Haill_Xamarin" 
             x:Class="Haill_Xamarin.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <local:page1 />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I updated it to what it should be in your case. However, you might want to check if you even have a `page1` at this point. If you do not understand this part, you will need much more than just a question here. Consider doing further learning and research, or seek help in other websites.

Comment: error ( Failed to resolve assembly: 'Haill_Xamarin, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' )

Comment: You should be putting your own assembly name and clr-namespace in the `local` declaration.

Comment: error : Additional information: Position 7:6. Type local:page1 not found in xmlns clr-namespace:Haill_Xamarin

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot help you any further. I've told you twice already what you're supposed to do. I cannot explain it any other way.